# Scrollable Pager Content Inside a NestedScrollView Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

[image]

I have a viewpager inside of a nested scroll view that may or may not contain data. If it does contain data, it is a two column staggered grid view that paginates. I want to be able to scroll down far enough where the above view is completely hidden and I can scroll the recycler view full screen. The problem I have is once the data loads in, I can only scroll a little bit more. It looks like the nested scroll range is extended by the height of the first item that appears in the recycler view. Is there something that I am missing?

Here is what is currently happening:
[image]

Where The entire view is scrollable when the items in the recycler view load but the scroll range only expands to the height of the first Item. I want to be able to scroll to the top of the tabs once the recycler loads like this image:

[image]

I am just confused on exactly what is happening here.

Here is the xml for the view in question

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/comment_layout_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/card_background">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/comment_footer"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collection_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/item_detail_container_height"
                android:background="@color/color_black"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />
            <Button
                style="@style/Button.LightPurple.Inverse"
                android:id="@+id/edit_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/collection_edit"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/item_detail_multi_nav_layout" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_list_divider" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/collection_title"
                android:layout_width="397dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/body_font_padding"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/live_action_item_name"
                android:textColor="@color/on_board_clubs_join_btn"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/collection_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/body_font_padding"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:text="@string/medal_item_description_placeholder"
                android:textColor="@color/color_dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/collection_item_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/body_font_padding"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/item_collection_count"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Large.Black.MontserratSemiBold"
                android:textColor="@color/search_follow_button"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/collection_uploadedby"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/body_font_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/item_uploaded_by"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Large.Black.Montserrat" />

            <include layout="@layout/action_feed_header_for_uploadedby" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="5dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="5dp"
            app:tabMinWidth="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/bpDark_gray"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/bpWhite" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_list_divider" />

        <com.gemr.android.widgets.misc.WrapContentViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/card_background"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/comment_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/card_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/color_list_divider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_box_layout"
        style="@style/comment_box_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bpWhite"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment_box"
            style="@style/comment_box_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/comment_text_box_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_post"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/comment_box_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/card_view_selector"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/comment_post"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Large.Gray.Montserrat" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the RecyclerView that is set up with the pager:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/card_background">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/feed_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:itemCount="3"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<include layout="@layout/fab_layout" />
```

Am I overlooking something very simple here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be this will help you

```
public class CustomNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView {
private int slop;
private float mInitialMotionX;
private float mInitialMotionY;

public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
    slop = config.getScaledEdgeSlop();
}

public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}


private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
            lastX = ev.getX();
            lastY = ev.getY();

            // This is very important line that fixes
            computeScroll();


            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float curX = ev.getX();
            final float curY = ev.getY();
            xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
            yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
            lastX = curX;
            lastY = curY;

            if (xDistance > yDistance) {
                return false;
            }
    }


    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Recyclerview` is set to `match_parent`. There for it's size will equal to the screen size minus the size of all other things in the `NestedScrollView` combined.

In a device which needs the whole screen to contain the other things in the `NestedScrollView`, the size of the `Recyclerview` will be even 0.

**Step 1:**
Change the height of the `Recyclerview` and its parents (`SwipeRefreshLayout`and `FrameLayout`) to `wrap_content`.

**Step 2:**
In case this doesn't work as expected, set a fixed size to `Recyclerview` (only to `Recyclerview` and the parents should remain `wrap_content`).

**Step 3:**
If you want it to work exactly as the provided image, I think you need to calculate the size at run-time. In that case you can undo the step 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the above steps and none seem to make any difference. Setting all the parents to wrap content left me in the same state and setting a fixed height on the recycler view, even a gigantic one, made no difference in the view as well

Comment: It should have been worked. Let me check it once again.

Comment: Try setting `RecyclerView` to `match_parent` along with step 1 and step 2.

Comment: Just tried setting it to match_parent with its parents as wrap content but still no results. I am really stumped on this one

Comment: The `RecyclerView` still has a fixed height, right?

Comment: Am I reading step 2 wrong with your previous comment. Your previous comment says to set RecyclerView to match_parent along with step 1 and step 2 but step two says to set a fixed size for RecyclerView. Are you referring to the method `setHasFixedSize()` if so this has been set with the value of true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178698/discussion-between-anees-and-murph-fish).